# NoClassDefFoundError Executable Jar

Tags: java, build, jar, dependencies, libraries

I’ve been tasked with adding a simple function to an old project that does not use a build tool like Maven or Gradle. I used some external libraries, namely jjwt-api, jjwt-impl & jjwt-jackson. To use the external libraries (in IntelliJ), I added the jar files to the “lib” folder, then checked the lib folder was included in File>Project Structure>Modules>Dependencies, with the Export option checked, and “Scope” set to Compile. The project runs fine in IntelliJ, but attempting to run the resulting build jar file causes the NoClassDefFoundError. I can see when browsing the jar file (as a zip file) that the classes are not present. How do I ensure the required classes are included in the build jar?

So far, I’ve tried adding the jars to Class-Path in the manifest.xml. I’ve looked at lots of posts/articles about the proper way to add dependencies in IntelliJ, but can’t see anything that differs from the process described above.

Comment: How do you build the jar?

Comment: Just using Build>RebuildProject or BuildArtifacts

Comment: It would be a good idea to overhaul the project so that you can use Maven to build it.   But what "manifest.xml" file are you talking about?  The class path in an executable JAR is specified in its "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" file!

Comment: Apologies. I meant manifest.mf. I spoke to someone else who worked on the same project a while ago. They attempted to use Maven but it appeared to cause more problems. The change I've made to the code is pretty minor, so would be ideal to simply get to build without the need for a build tool.

Comment: Well ... any problems with using Maven should be surmountable.  My guess is that that person was not very familiar with Maven (at that time) and/or made some mistakes.

Comment: But adding something to the `Class-Path` attribute of a `MANIFEST.MF` file does not cause the corresponding classes to be included in the JAR.  Rather you are specifying a bunch of locations for external JARs to be added to the classpath *at run time*.  If said JARs are not where the attribute says they should be *at runtime* you will get missing classes.  Basically, that attribute is rather fragile.  A better idea is to create a fat JAR / uberJAR ... and Maven knows how to do that.  (Yet another reason to switch.)

Comment: Might attempt to migrate to Maven.

Comment: Initial attempt to use Maven gives "multiple points" error. The project structure is a mess. Not sure if the time required to restructure the project be worth it, or simply cause more problems.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by the absence of the relevant artifacts in Project Settings:

1. File-> Project Settings -> Artifacts
2. In RH window: Output Layout -> + -> File
3. Select the required jar in the ‘lib’ directory
4. The extracted file is added to the list of artifacts

The built jar file worked perfectly after following this procedure.